# Somar o total dos valores de cada chave dos dicionários em Python

Tags: python, dicionário

Tenho a seguinte lista de dicionários em Python :

```
creches = [
    {
        "nome": "Recanto do Sol",
        "cachorros": 12,
        "gatos": 4,
        "coelhos": 2,
    },
    {
        "nome": "Lar dos bichos",
        "cachorros": 8,
        "gatos": 5,
        "porquinhos-da-índia": 3,
    },
    {
        "nome" : "A Fazenda",
        "cachorros": 20,
        "coelhos": 10,
    },
    {
        "nome": "Casa da alegria",
        "gatos": 15,
        "porquinhos-da-índia": 7,
    },
]
```

Preciso que o output seja:

```
quantidade_de_animais_por_especie = {
    "cachorros": 100,
    "gatos": 70,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta criar um dicionário totalmente vazio para armazenar as somas e percorrer cada animal de cada creche — verificando se a chave é diferente de `"nome"`. Dessa forma, você pode computar a quantidade de ilimitadas espécies de animais, sem precisar modificar algo no código.

Abaixo está uma função simples para realizar essa tarefa:

```
def obter_quantidade_de_animais(registro, excluir = ()):

    resultado = {}
    
    for creche in registro:
        for key in creche:
            if not key in excluir:
                resultado[key] = resultado.get(key, 0) + creche[key]

    return resultado
```

Note que a função possui um parâmetro chamado `excluir`. Através desse parâmetro, você pode adicionar chaves para serem ignoradas ao computar os dados, como no exemplo abaixo, onde a chave `"nome"` é ignorada, contabilizando os dados das outras chaves — no caso, animais.

```
resultado = obter_quantidade_de_animais(creches, ("nome", ))
# {'cachorros': 40, 'gatos': 24, 'coelhos': 12, 'porquinhos-da-índia': 10}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajudar.